# Weighted randomization generation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, weighted, weibull

I want to generate a weighted randomized distribution of 150k values where the weights in the distribution are given by F(v) (see attached image of Weibull distribution) in Python. So, based on the equation the code should generate 150k values ranging from 0 to 30 (which is v).
And those 150k values can be any real number within the range and not just integers and the chances of number lying in the lower-middle range will be higher as this function peaks at that range.
Note: m,c,k are constant and v is the only variable of which we want the 150k values.

[Weibull Distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnvvK.png)

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.weibull.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [surpyval](https://surpyval.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to do this (I am it's developer) . Surpyval uses the parameters alpha, beta, and gamma for the Weibull distribution. Alpha, beta, and gamma are equivalent to the parameters c, k, and m respectively in the image you provided.

The below code creates the distribution from c, k, and m then generates 150k random variables from that distribution.

```py
from surpyval import Weibull

k = 1.5
c = 50.3
m = 25.

model = Weibull.from_params((c, k), gamma=m)

# generate random variables
random_values = model.random(150000)
```