# Weibull weighted randomization in Python

Tags: python, random, weibull

How to use Weibull function to generate random numbers within a given range?  I know there is a scipy function
`weibull_min.rvs(k, loc=0, scale=lam, size=n, random_state=5)`
that generates `n` number of points when given shape and scale parameters, but I want it to generate random numbers within a fixed range, not all values.

Note: the range might be a set of integers like between 2 and 3, then Generate random numbers between them that follow the Weibull distribution.

Comment: `weibull_min.rvs` is **not** built-in; it comes from Scipy, which is a third-party add-on. Anyway, did you try putting `python weibull distribution` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+weibull+distribution)? Did you try reading the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.weibull_min.html) for `weibull_min`? Did you try checking the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) for the standard library `random` module?

Comment: Also, it isn't really clear what you want. What "dataset" are you talking about? What kind of "points" do you expect to get from the function, and *how do those relate to your data*? Are you trying to *fit* a Weibull distribution to some data? Because that is a different question from simply generating one with specified parameters. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and explain: what input do you give to the program? What should happen with that input?

Comment: I did read the documentation and went through the documentation before asking the question. I have been stuck on the problem for few days that's why I asked. You don't have to be rude.  In a weibull, when you give in shape and scale parameters it just generates datapoints starting from 0 to a max value depending on how many points you give in. What I wanted was it to generate subset of the entire points it generate within a range specified say (2,3)

Comment: Input: Shape, Scale, Range:(a,b), No. of points (n). n=10,a=2,b=3 Output: No between 2 and 3 that follows Weibull distribution

Comment: I am trying to generate data within a range not fit Weibull to different data

Comment: "when you give in shape and scale parameters it just generates datapoints starting from 0 to a max value depending on how many points you give in. What I wanted was it to generate subset of the entire points it generate within a range specified say (2,3)" I can't understand **why this is a problem**. How is "from 0 to a max value", not "a range"? If the problem is that the values have a minimum of 0 and you want them to have a minimum of 2 instead... why not just generate values from 0 to 1, and add 2 to each one?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel your comments are very obtuse and aggressive.  I believe the question is very clear.  And note that for most distributions, the dist between (e.g.) (2, 3) is NOT the same as between (0, 1) and adding 2!  If you don't understand the question, you can simply not respond to it.

@sincold you will likely either need to reject points outside of your desired range until you have enough points, or write your own `rv_continuous` subclass that only draws from a given range.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71215757/weighted-randomization-generation-in-python

Comment: " If you don't understand the question, you can simply not respond to it." The *point* of comments is to clarify the question. If there is something special about the distribution then *that should be explicit in the question*; this is Stack Overflow, not math.SE. More importantly, the question should be clear about the actual desired distribution. For example: should it be the result of truncating the original distribution to [2,3], setting it zero everywhere else, and renormalizing? Or **just what**? Because there are many other possibilities.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix I am not trying to be aggressive in the slightest. My claim is that the question is not clear at all. If someone is asking "why doesn't this obvious, simple thing solve the problem?", and it doesn't actually solve the problem, the correct conclusion should be that the problem is more complex than it superficially appears.

Answer (score 1):

You are after random values from a [truncated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution) distribution, specifically a truncated Weibull distribution.

Truncation is essentially where any values that are above or below the truncated values are 'filtered out'.

You can use [surpyval](https://surpyval.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (I am it's developer) to sample from a truncated Weibull distribution:

```py
from surpyval import Weibull

alpha = 6
beta = 3

model = Weibull.from_params((alpha, beta))

# Lower and Upper limit of truncation
a, b = 2, 3

# get n samples
n = 100

# Get the random values
vals_between_2_and_3 = model.random(n, a=a, b=b)
```

Comment: surpypal looks nice -- well-written doc. Could you point me to an intro to survival with a cost function, e.g. min expected cost( Weibull-random X ) ? Thanks

Comment: Thanks @denis. Apologies, but I am not sure what you mean. Did you mean a survival model which for each 'x' there is also a cost? And you want the expected value of cost?

Comment: Yes that's right: I have a fixed cost function f() and can of course crank out f( samples X_i ), but my results are not very intuitive so am looking for other examples of this kind. Thanks